# Track git pushes and checkout

Tags: git, version-control, file, sharing

Currently, I distribute files to my customers through git, and would like to observe situation - who from my customers updated required files, who`s not, so is there any way to track that specific customer

- a) git pulled from git server
- b) git checkout
  successfully

?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have filesystem access to the customers' repos, or do they handle the git stuff themselves? If it's their responsibility, are you giving them scripts which run the appropriate git operations, or do they do it manually?

Comment: @Jefromi, in perfect world I would like to see on git server some logs, such as - client with ip pulled version at time, is it possible?

Comment: What transport do you use for pulls?  HTTP? SSH?

Comment: But it matters for the answer :) For example, when using HTTP, you can just look at the logs of your web server to get the information you want (except for the information on checkouts, because those are completely local to your customer's machine).

Answer (score 1):

`git push` performed by a customer adds commits from that customer to your repo -- you should be able to see if there are new commits which originate from your customers by using `git log` or similar.  You can also activate the [reflogs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-reflog.html) of the branches and see the pushes there.  For a bare repository, reflogs are disabled by default and can be enabled by setting the [configuration variable](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-config.html) `core.logAllRefUpdates` to `true`.

For `git cehckout`, you won't have a chance to see this because it is a completely local operation that happens on your customer's machine.

Comment: I want to see git pulls, not pushes.