# Report who is doing a pull/checkout/fetch on my git repo

Tags: git, history

How do I know who is pulling from my git repo?  Or doing a git fetch origin?  Obviously I can look at git log to see the pushes/commits, but is there any way to see if people are just pulling my code to read it or stay synched up?

Here is some context.  First off, the closest match on stackoverflow I could find was [Track git pushes and checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127466/track-git-pushes-and-checkout) but the question didn't satisfactorily get resolved.  I decided to pull this into a different question because it is slightly different...

The environment is git repository server that is acting as a central repo that developers are cloning from and pushing changes back into.  The central repo is the one that gets built in continuous integration and releases are done from that code base.

I have a variety of user management tools: gerrit, gitosis, and gitolite.

Why would I want to know this and why would it be relevant to you too?  In my case I want to know who's working on what...who's looking at what.  That info can help decide what projects are no longer maintained/interesting and can possibly be shelved.  It can also help create ugly managerial metrics (not a fan of this really, but it is a necessity in the business) of who is active.  Git log will show who's committing code, which is more telling on productivity, but not if people are not pushing frequently.  I really cant think of any other use cases, but those are my two.

So...any way to pull that info from git directly?  I remember CVS history would give some of that, but I cant figure it out in git.  If not git directly, what about gerrit, gitosis, or gitolite?

Thanks.

Comment: Cloning/pulling doesn't affect the source repo. They're completely read-only operations. There is no way to track this with git; you need to track this at the authentication level.

Answer (score 1):

The first toolset I would look to for solving such a task would be to try using Git + WebDAV on Apache. With authentication and access logs, that may provide you the information you're looking for. That failing, you may be in the position to write a custom Git server. As Git was designed to be decentralized, and clients can operate without ever talking to your chosen server, I believe the functionality for tracking retrievals isn't part of the core.

Comment: Why WebDAV? May be just plain git-http-backend?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with that particular back-end, but after looking into it, I'd suggest using that.

Comment: git-http-backend sounds cool, but would be a lot of coordinated upgrades to the newer version of git.  We are still on 1.6.3.3.  Server-side would be easy through IT, but the variety of client installations that are unfortunately unmanaged would cause an interruption of service that isn't worth it for so low-priority a task.  I appreciate opening my eyes to git-http-backend though...I'll be reading more on it.